# Selected part of render rendered transparent

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, transparency, error

I am having a problem with rendering selected parts of render. Full render was done fine, no problems, but when I want to re-render some selected parts it turning out like this?
[image]

When it render everything look fine until its done. Its just turning like that… How I can fix that?

Comment: As you haven't provided any images of what you are trying to render or of the settings you are using it's impossible to answer that question!